# Import excel file which is on local machine to SQL server 2005

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, import

I have a path to an Excel file which is located on my local machine and I want to import the data of the Excel file to SQL Server 2005.

I have tried this code but it gives me an error:

```
string sSourceConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + textBox1 + "; Extended Properties=" + "\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;+\"";
        string dDestConStr = @"server=severIPAddress;database=databaseName;uid=userName;password=pwd";


        OleDbConnection sSourceConnection = new OleDbConnection(sSourceConStr);
        using (sSourceConnection)
        {
            string sql = string.Format("Select * FROM [{0}]", "Sheet1$");
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, sSourceConnection);
            sSourceConnection.Open();
            using (OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(dDestConStr))
                {
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.databaseName";            
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                }
            }
        }
```

Error:

> OleDBException was unhandled. Failure creating file.

What would cause this and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change textBox1 to textBox1.Text in Data Source